# How to set child text color of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, colors, set, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView in an activity. The code is:

```
  final ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);  
  expandableListView.setDivider(null);
  expandableListView.setCacheColorHint(0);
  expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
  final EEInterviewExpandableListAdapter adapter = new EEInterviewExpandableListAdapter(this);  
  expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And related code in the adapter is:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String string = pageArray.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition); 
    boolean highlight=false;
    return getChildGenericView(string,highlight);    
}
public TextView getChildGenericView(String string,boolean highlight)    
{    
    // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView    
    AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(    
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView text = new TextView(activity);    
    text.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);    
    // Center the text vertically    
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);    
    // Set the text starting position    
    text.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 2);    
    text.setText(string.trim());    
    text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.childsep);
    if(highlight)
        text.setTextColor(R.color.expchdhighlightcolor);
    else
        text.setTextColor(R.color.expchdcolor);
    text.setTextSize(EEEnv.EEfontSize);
   return text;    
}
```

My problem is the settextcolor() doesn't work. I searched on the web. And it is said that expandableListView.setCacheColorHint(0); can resolve it. But the problem is still there. Anybody know this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access certain XML resources like this:

```
text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.expchdhighlightcolor));
```

Otherwise you are passing the unique id that references the resource... Notice the difference when you run this:

```
Log.v("Test", "Not what I expected: " + R.color.expchdhighlightcolor);
Log.v("Test", "The hex value in decimal: " + getResources().getColor(R.color.expchdhighlightcolor));
```